# Responsive mail not working in Outlook(hotmail)

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, outlook, hotmail

I have been using [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/1506390-Free-Psd-html-Responsive-Email-Template?list=users&offset=11) free responsive email template. I have mainly been using the same .html, except from some small changes her and there regarding text and images. The email displays correctly in browsers like chrome and firefox and in Gmail, but not in Outlook! How can I make the images display in line also for Outlook?

**UPDATE:** 
If someone has a suggestion for another responsive email template that also will work in outlook I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can find the supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

You can a reference to an external images, also you can embedd an image. To get this done, you need to attach it as a file. Set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property (DASL - "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E")  using the  Attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty method. The value should match the cid attribute of the image. See [Outlook 2010- Create a message from an HTM file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/733bbc4f-2bdc-4d73-83c1-9a46585859bf/outlook-2010-create-a-message-from-an-htm-file?forum=outlookdev) for more information.

```
 newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format(
 "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>"
, contentIdValue
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Outlook on your desktop, outlook.com or the outlook app on your smartphone?

Outlook desktop will not display emails responsively.
Outlook.com is hard as you can't really re-size the window to show it working.
Outlook app is your best bet as it display your responsive email just fine.

Can you confirm which of these is your scenario?